# push notifications with tag and sub tags at IBM WL\MF 7.1.0.00

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

i wanna develop possibility of send push notification with tags and sub tags,
the only information that i read was with only one level tag. maybe, there is an option that to thread the tags and sub tags, but if i want to send push notification and the user register to more than one tag \ sub tag he will get the notification twice (or more)?
is someone had this challenge?
I'd love to get ideas for solutions.

thanks you all,
sahar

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to create "sub tags". There is only one level of tags.

You could possibly control this with some logic before sending the notification.

If I recall your project you have a PHP script that sends the call to the adapter to send the push notification, in this case if the tag is also a "parent tag" (such as "news", which is a tag like "sports", "politics", "tech"), then when constructing the request, use only "news" and not also another notification per "child tag".

Edit: per the comment where you're asking about using adapters, you should be able to implement this also in an adapter, since in the adapter you obtain a list of tags, so that's where you could also decide to which tags to send the notification: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/TagNotifications/blob/release71/adapters/PushAdapter/PushAdapter-impl.js#L29

Comment: since, its change to C#, but there is an option to distinct with the adapter?

Comment: Yes, I believe you should be able to write this logic in an adapter as well. See my edited answer.

Comment: there is an option that the user related to two or more sub categories, but when I broadcast the push message and choose two or more tags i wanna avoid user gets 2 or more notification at the same time. i don't see where to "distinct" the  user subscription\ deviceid ...

Comment: Read my answer again. That's exactly the logic you need to write... in the code example in the link you provide the tags ("notificstionTags"), you need to check which tags are there: news, sports, tech... so for example since news = sports + tech, then construct the notification so that it'll be sent only once... I can't help you write this logic. It depends on your needs.